# application writing to the disk continuously

Tags: ios, xcode, io, instruments, disk

I don't get this thing... xcode shows, that my application continuously writing to the disk at least 80 kb/s. I totally commented out all methods, so there is just one thing, a navigation controller in the app. And it still shows this. I tried to use instruments but sadly i didn t become smarter. And there is another thing, my phone warming up in a few minutes

Anybody can help me or explain what is this? Here are a few photos
[image: Xcode]
[image: Open Files]
[image: Instrumetns]

Comment: The gauge tells you what the open files are, but you have omitted that from the screen shot.

Comment: @matt I attached that too

Comment: But you cut off the important information, namely what the files _are_. With all those files open, you're lying — you don't just have a navigation controller. It seems like you're not serious about trying to understand this.

Comment: There are only SDKs like firebase and mixpanel, no more. But I m not able to expand this panel to see the whole path. @matt

Comment: The Open Files section is horizontally scrollable. I think you'll discover that Firebase is doing this work.